# Visual Studio does not highlight matching braces in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio

My Visual Studio no longer highlights matching braces in JS/TS files. It works in C#. How to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close Visual Studio and delete your user settings file (e.g. `MyProject.csproj.user`) in the porject folder. Worked for me!